# How to model JSON with key value pairs?

Tags: java, json, gson

This simple JSON is returned by https://httpbin.org/get which is handy for testing.

```
{
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "0",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "AemSConnector v1.0",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-606c333f-338353e14fc31e375617f4ba"
  },
  "origin": "81.40.159.142",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get"
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to build a Java class to model this.

I have tried:

```
public class ModelTest {
    public String origin;
    public String url;
    public HashMap<String, String> headers;
    public HashMap<String, String> args;

    // getters and setters and default constructor here...
  }
}
```

And also just this:

```
public class ModelTest {
    public String origin;
    public String url;

    // getters and setters and default constructor here...
  }
}
```

But when I try to convert the JSON string to this model, I just get a null point exception in the logs, no helpful info.

The code I am using is this:

```
// ModelTest model = null;
ModelTest model = new ModelTest();
model = (ModelTest) getObjectFromJson(reply, model);
}
:
public static Object getObjectFromJson(String jsonString, Object obj) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object returnValue = null;
    try {
        returnValue = gson.fromJson(jsonString, obj.getClass());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception occured in Something :: getObjectFromJson --> ", e);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

exception:

```
2021-04-06 12:09:04.245 ERROR [com.adobe.aem.guides.wknd.core.util.MyConnector] Exception occured in Something :: getObjectFromJson -->
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.adobe.aem.guides.wknd.core.util.SpineConnector.getObjectFromJson(MyConnector.java:77) [aem-guides-wknd.core:0.2.1.SNAPSHOT]
        at com.adobe.aem.guides.wknd.core.util.SpineConnector.get(MyConnector.java:50) [aem-guides-wknd.core:0.2.1.SNAPSHOT]
        at com.adobe.aem.guides.wknd.core.servlets.SpineServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:64) [aem-guides-wknd.core:0.2.1.SNAPSHOT]
```

Comment: From what I understand the model which passed to getObjectFromJson is a null object and thus the NullPointerException

Comment: create a dummy model object and send it to the function and check if you are able to re-assign the model .

Comment: Your `model` object is null.

Comment: you can try replacing gson.fromJson(jsonString, obj.getClass) to gson.fromJson(jsonString, Model.class)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The Model was fine, it was the getObjectFromJson method which was causing the issues, even with a non-null object (as the commenters pointed out)

I scrapped it, and did the mapping in-line and it worked as expected:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    model = gson.fromJson(reply, ModelTest.class);
```